How can I predict ordered classes from unstructured text documents?
I have a number of unstructured text documents, each of which is a list of responsibilities. I plan to use some embedding to vectorise them (SBERT?).
My target variables (I have multiple) represent aspects that each document should be graded on, such as complexity, agency, and skills required. They are numeric, but the difference between them is not meaningful. For example, for "agency", the values might be interpreted as follows:
1 - Solely following fixed instructions that never change, with no room for judgement or interpretation
2 - Solely following fixed instructions that never change, with some room for judgement or interpretation
3 - Solely following fixed instructions that may occasionally change, with some room for judgement or interpretation
Each value is in some sense "greater" than the one before, which leads me to believe that ordinal classification is appropriate here. I've seen similar problems solved with regression + clipping (reviews come to mind) - would that work too?
